# Can I pass a prop component to mui styled()?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

Is it possible to pass a prop component to the mui styled utility?

I am passing an icon component from parent to child and would like pass this icon into a styled component within the child.

Parent:

```
export const ButtonWithIcon = Template.bind({});
ButtonWithIcon.args = {
  icon: (
    <AddIcon
      style={{
        color: 'red',

      }}
    />
  ),
};
```

Child:

```
const {
    icon,
  } = props;

  const StyledIcon = styled(icon)(({ theme }) => ({
    color: theme.colors.primary
  }));
```

Is this possible? icon is a component but getting errors when trying to pass it in to the styled utility

Comment: For context, I'm trying to change the color of an icon that is passed in depending on whatever variant of the button is chosen. If I pass in the icon with the color as white then want to change it, could i do this with styled?

Answer (score 1):

Since this is an old question, I'm hoping you got your answer. But for reference, this is most certainly possible.

```js
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Box } from '@mui/material';
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
import theme from '../../themes/appTheme';

const StyledBox = styled(Box)(({ anyStyling }) => {
  // Custom styling
});

export default function SomeWrapper(props) {
  const { children, anyStyling } = props;
  return <StyledBox {...props}>{children}</StyledBox>;
}

SomeWrapper.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
};
```